# when a button is clicked it should fire of an input click in typescript

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, color-picker

i have a color picker thats displayed on a page, if you click it,it drops down the colors for you to select.

But what i want to do is that i want to hide the color picker and only when a button  is clicked i want it to automatically click the color picker so that the drop down colors is shown instead of me clicking on the color picker

```html
<button click.delegate="test">Select a Color</button>

<input type="color" id="color"></input>
```

this is what i tried

```
 <input type="color" id="color" style="display:none"></input>
    test() {
            let color = document.getElementById("color")
              color.style.display = "block";
            if (color instanceof HTMLElement) {
                color.click();
            }
        }
```

but the above doesnt work, it doesnt invoke a click to dropdown the color gradients

so basically when the button is clicked this is what it should look like

[image]

Comment: Well, I copied your code to an example page on w3schools, it actually works by fixing some errors such as adding "function" keyword to the left of "test()" .   Here is  screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/kuSxlK4   Though I tested on Firefox

Comment: i am using typescript  and aurelia so it doesnt like it that way

Comment: Sorry, I missed typescript part :/ Can you check the console of the browser via inspection. Maybe there are some errors thrown. It might give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```js
function showColorPickerFunc() {
  let el = document.getElementById("color") 
     if (el.onclick) {
       el.onclick();
    } else if (el.click) {
       el.click();
    }
  }
        

showColorPickerFunc();
```

```css
#color{
  width: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="showColorPickerFunc()">Select a Color</button>

<input type="color" id="color"  />
```